# Understanding Erlang types with type variables

Tags: types, erlang

In Erlang, you can have a type declaration parameterized with type variables e.g.

```
-type dict(K, V) :: [{K,V}].
```

`K, V` are type variables i.e. they can be replaced in subsequent type declarations or function specifications with concrete types. E.g.

```
-type catalog() :: dict(string(), integer()).
```

Here `K` is replaced with type `string()`, and `V` with type `integer()`.
Or, it can be used in function specifications e.g.

```
-spec find(string(), dict(string(), any())) -> any().
```

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes. it is correct.

Comment: Could I call it generic type declaration?

Comment: Yes, it could, sort of.

Comment: Maybe polymorphic types is a better name http://learnyousomeerlang.com/dialyzer#polymorphic-types